# minimize and maximize the map using fingers only - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

I have an application built in Html5 and wrapped in PhoneGap.

In my application I use Google's map-Map,

In the smartphone I cant minimize and maximize the map using fingers only,

Is there a setting that should allow to be possible to do so?

Comment: u mean u want to hide zoom control buttons?

Comment: Also .. But mostly I want to be possible to zoom with the fingers, because now it is not enabled ..

Comment: Have you looked at these related questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905902/android-pinch-zoom-in-google-maps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166432/pinch-to-zoom-google-maps-api-v3-android-webkit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551597/pinch-zoom-out-in-google-maps-in-android

Comment: All of these questions are talking about Android applications, my application written in Html5 and JS (I use PhoneGap), Is it possible to set from JS be possible to minimize and maximize the map with a touch on Smartphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On more **advanced** versions of smartphone,

the zoom by the fingers only **works**!

Then to old versions I added **zoom buttons**.